# Getting pagination to work w/ nested {exp:channel:entry} tags?

Tags: templates, pagination

I'm working on a blog site that uses a base index file as a "driver", with embedded templates for all the important data. The embedded templates both have {exp:channel:entry} tags that display a certain # of blog entries. Each template is formatted differently per the certain # of blog entries being shown, as I wanted the last four entries to look different than the first four.

The issue I'm having with pagination is that in the index files {exp:channel:entry} tag, I've set the limit to 1, and now it's giving me 10 pages worth of results (which is the total # of entries I have), but what I really want is just normal pagination that shows eight entries per page, formatted as I normally do.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<? //Formats article page w/ embedded EE variables. ?>

{embed="home/header" page-title="Lean Articles"}
{embed="resources/subhead"}

<? //Container for multiple blog articles, 700px wide defined by Grid system. ?> 

{embed="a_update/article-nav"}

{if segment_2 == "" || segment_2 == "category" || segment_2 == "P1"}

    <span class="rightcol-700">

<?//Embed main and side content for Homepage section of site.?>

{exp:channel:entries channel="aupdate" limit="1" paginate="bottom" orderby="desc" dynamic="off"}
    {embed="a_update/.hidden_main_content"}
    {embed="a_update/.hidden_side_content"}

       {paginate}
              <p id="pagination">Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
      {/paginate} 

{/exp:channel:entries}

    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this not just limit="8", or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It would be, but within those embeds are channel entry tags that have each display a limit of 4, with different styling, such as:

```
<div style="width:400px;float:left;padding-right: 30px; border-right:solid 1px #3e3e3e">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="aupdate" limit="4"}
                    <div style="font-size:14px;color:#2b637e;font-weight:bold;line-height:1.2em">
                        <a href="{site_url}/a_update/{url_title}" style="text-decoration: none;">{title}</a>
                    </div>
    <?//Article date token, taken from Date field in Article channel. ?>
                    <div style="font-size:11px;color:#959190;line-height:1.6em">
                        {entry_date format="%F %d, %Y"}
                    </div>
    <?//Article Banner Image.?>
                    <div>
                        {exp:ed_imageresizer image="{article_image}" maxWidth="200px" maxHeight="80px" class="banner_image"}{/exp:ed_imageresizer}
                    </div>

     <?//Article summary token, taken from Summary field in Article channel. ?>
                    <p>{article_summary}</p>                        
                    <div>
                        [ <a href="{site_url}/a_update/{url_title}">read more</a> ]
                    </div>
                    <br clear="all">
                    <hr>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```

And the second embed:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="aupdate" limit="4" offset="4"}

<div style="width:165px;float:left;padding-left:30px;">
        <div style="font-size:12px; color: black;font-weight: normal;">
            <p><a href="{site_url}/a_update/{url_title}">{title}</a></p>
        </div>  
        <div style="font-size:11px;color:#959190;line-height:1.6em">
            {entry_date format="%F %d, %Y"}
        </div>
        <p>{article_promo}</p>
        <hr>
</div>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So if I set the limit to 8, what happens is that it returns all my results squared, effectively, displaying way too many results/duplicates on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to change `limit="1"` to `limit="8"` on your channel:entries tag unless I'm missing something.